# How to fetch data from database to JSON (brackets)?

Tags: php, jquery, brackets

I'm trying to figure out how can I get the results from database to this JSON request. I'm using [this](http://www.aropupu.fi/bracket/) script I have 8 teams in the "clans" table and want to randomize these 8 teams in the first round from database.

This code works well, but how can I fetch team 1, team 2, etc from the "clans" table? (all rounds are 'null' because I want to put scores manually)

```
var mindata = {
     teams:[

     ["Team 1", "Team 2"],
     ["Team 3", "Team 4"],
     ["Team 5", "Team 6"],
     ["Team 7", "Team 8"]




 ],
     results : [
         [[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null]],
         [ [null,null],[null,null]],
         [[null,null], [null,null] ]


     ] }
    $('.tournament').bracket({
        init:mindata
    });
```

Comment: Build the full array and `echo json_encode($clanname_array);`

Comment: Ok, I will try to build in arrays. And yes my bad, it's JSON. I'm just tried to outputting the $clanname in the json code, `teams:[

     [<?php echo $clanname; ?>] ],` but yeah, now I know that was bullsh*t and maybe I need to do in arrays.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question with the code what I am tried

Comment: So the question is: how can I add an extra "[" before every string(Team 1, Team 2 etc) and an extra "]" after every second string ?

Comment: echo json_encode(array_chunk($rows,2));

Comment: Almost fine with this , but it's displays like this: `[[["Team 1"],["Team 2"]],[["Team 3"],["Team 4"]],[["Team 5"],["Team 6"]],[["Team 7"],["Team 8"]]]` How can I delete one of the "[" from before and one of "]" after?

Comment: it is your expected result, you can't get json as a list of inner items of array, only full array

Comment: I just don't need one of the "[" at the beggining and one of the "]" in the end

Comment: remove them by `preg_replace('~^\[|\]$~'...`